# Symfony 3 - [KNP Pagination and sorting] Sorting for native query issue

Tags: php, symfony, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

In my application I am using two databases, One is application database and another one is used to fetch data for the application [Using normal sql statements to fetch data]

I want to display 2nd database's data in my application, everything is working fine, even pagination but I don't know how to implement sorting. Using Knp-pagination bundle.

Pagination and sorting are working fine for the application database's data.

Here is the code

**Controller**

```
$db = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('2ndDatabase');
        $sql = "select * from table1, table2 where somevariable_id = ? and table1.id = table2.id and rownum<=50";
        $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam('1', $somevariableidvalue);
        $statement->execute();
        $data = $statement->fetchall();

    /**
     * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
     */
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $result = $paginator->paginate(
        $data,
        $request->query->getInt('page',1),
        $request->query->getInt('limit', 10)
    )
```

**View**

```
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(data, 'ID', 'whattowritehere') }}</th>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(data, 'Title', 'whattowritehere') }}</th>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(data, 'Name', 'whattowritehere') }}</th>
```

In place of whattowritehere tried different things trying to access table, But I don't think I can access it without model/entity. I dont have any model/entity defined for 2nd Database, so finding it hard to create a entity manager to make sql into dql statement.

- Can I make this sql into dql (That will solve my problem! I don't have entity manager defined for this database, and there is no model/entity to the database)
- Is there a way to manipulate the `$data` since it working for pagination, I am thinking there might be a way for sorting as well
- Am I missing something ?
- Is it even possible to do ?

whattowritehere - tried column name (doesn't work, no error)
                - data.variablename (data release is array, expecting         object)         - array reference (same error)

Comment: The value of `whattowritehere` would be your column names. Have you tried that? I'm not sure if it will work though. I'm using DQL.

Comment: Ya, tried columns names, but didn't work.

Comment: If you're using both tables, you'll definitely need a `JOIN` in your sql statement. Try doing the pagination with only one `<th>` being sortable; that's how I troubleshooted. Once you get one working, the other ones should be easier. Maybe even to troubleshoot, try just querying TABLE2 only.